# PSP game not saving - requires memory stick

Tags: ps-vita, assassins-creed-series

I'm playing Assassin's Creed for PSP right now and it says that it cannot save because it requires a memory stick (for PSP). How can I fix this? (I have the memory card (32GB) for the PS Vita)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A forum thread here http://psvitaforum.com/threads/psp-game-not-saving-requires-memory-stick.7680/page-2 says reinstalling the game might solve the issue, I would try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per JohnoBoy's link, I had reinstalled the game and the problem promptly disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a compatibility issue with the PSP game on your Vita. Try contacting Sony Customer Service or see if there is a patch available for the game to fix the issue.